# Kubernetes Node unable to access Docker Private Registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, docker-api

I've setup kubernetes cluster which has 3 worker node with docker private registry service.  The master node is able to login into Private Registry, but worker nodes can't login due to 503 Service unavailable. There is no error log in the Private Registry pod. How do I debug it?

```
[root@worker]# docker login -u test -p test123 1.1.1.1:5000
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://1.1.1.1:5000/v2/ failed with status: 503 
Service Unavailable
```

PS : The Private Registry is insecure so all nodes has `insecure-regies: ["1.1.1.1"]` configuration. Also I've changed IP addresses. Registry is installed by `helm install twuni/docker-registry --generate-name` nothing more

Comment: How you configured docker registry, can you mention that in your question.

Comment: @mchawre updated thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @NaiameNel'Theri Could you please try to add port `:5000` to your `insecure-regies`? Are you sure the the Registry is UP when you try to login from worker nodes?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor thanks for your advice. But the nodes already has the configuration. and I've solved issue by setting NO_PROXY environment. It seems like nodes are trying to connect with registry using proxy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by setting NO_PROXY environment on all nodes. Apparently the nodes are trying to connect with registry using PROXY even though there was none configured. I found out this by using `kubectl describe pod`